# Open an ASPX page from the sitemap in CRM 4 and 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

What I would like to do is to place an item on the `sitemap` that doesn't lead to a CRM page but would open `www.MyNewPage.aspx`. I need to do this programmatically and an `iFrame` in a CRM page is not what I'm looking for.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add html pages as webresources. You can make those webresources targets for sitemap entires like this in your sitemap, notice the url.

```
      <SubArea Id="nav_yourlink" Url="$webresource:new_mynewpage.htm" Icon="$webresource:new_image.png">
        <Titles>
          <Title LCID="1033" Title="my title" />
        </Titles>
        <Descriptions>
          <Description LCID="1033" Description="my descr"/>
        </Descriptions>
      </SubArea>
```

Then you can embed whatever javascript you want in that html page to launch your webpage. The two main ways to launch a new page from javascript:

```
window.location = 'www.mydomain.com/mypage.aspx'; // set the content INSIDE crm's content pane.
```

or (sounds like this one is what you want)

```
window.open('www.mydomain.com/mypage.aspx'); // open it in a new window, leaving CRM's content pane blank.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution I came up with as well after playing with the SiteMap editor off Codeplex yesterday. It's good to have confirmation and a nice example of the xml. =)

Comment: I guess I can't edit my comment...

In the URL of the SubArea, are queyrstring params acceptable or would it break the webresource?

Comment: good question, I dont know. Give it a shot and let us know? Also, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx for context variables if you need them. I've used that to enable my js to hit the OData endpoint in the past and stored information in CRM that eventually gets used in the html page. So perhaps you can use that if querystring params dont work.

Comment: @ Justin willams, i think you can, the following link is discussing this  "Passing Parameters to a URL Using SiteMap" : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328374(v=crm.5).aspx